What features require IE 11 Compatibility Mode
I need to update a legacy web site which currently runs in IE 11 compatibility mode in Edge  so that it can directly in Edge. I can find lots of references to how to turn on compatibility mode but I am struggling to find what are the features of this web site which require compatibility mode. So far the only one I have found is that the site invokes a large number of processes using ActiveX. I know how to fix these but are there other features/technologies which require compatibility mode.

You can hardly find such references, because it is hard to conclude what you need modify to make it compatible with Edge. You can first run your application under Edge mode, then you need tools like F12 Developer Tools and references like Can I use to help you troubleshoot compatibility issues. You can even contact Microsoft App Assure support to help you migrate your application, if you think it will take too much time.
Known features that are not supported in Edge are ActiveX controls (such as Java or Silverlight), which you have already got in mind.

Thanks - I will fix the ActiveX interfaces and then run the browser in Edge to see what breaks.
